# How to check if a string is between 2 Strings, and return the following characters with regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to check if a String is in a text file, between two other Strings, and if true, return the very next String matching a regex...

And I have no clue how to achieve it!

Since you're maybe lost with my explanation, I'll explain it better with my problem:

I'm creating an app (in python) reading a pdf and converting it in .txt.

In this txt, I would like to find the `pH` and return it. I know that I will find it between section 10 and 11, like this :

```
10. blablablablabla pH 7,6 blablablabla 11.
```

So

1. How can I reduce my research between `"10."` and `"11."`?
2. for the pH part, I think this is something like :

   `if 'pH' in open(file).read():`
3. If we find 'ph', how can I code that I would like the next String obeying this regex : `re.search("[0-9]{1}[,.]?[0-9]?", file)`

Comment: what do you mean by "I would like the next string obeying this regex"? Can you put more explicitly what you would want returned given your example string?

Comment: Sorry for being so unclear... I mean: my loop finds "pH" so I would like to return the next String, following "pH" that equals my regex. In my example above, the next string after pH that equals my regex is "7,6", so I would like to return 7,6. Clear enough I hope!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following:

```
regex = re.compile(r"\b10\.(?:(?!\b11\.|\bpH\b).)*\bpH\b\s*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)(?=.*\b11\.)", re.DOTALL)
pH = regex.search(my_string).group(1)
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eV1vZ7/1).

What it does is match a pH value only if it's found between `10.` and `11.`, and if there is more than one, it finds the first one.

**Explanation:**

```
\b10\.        # Match 10. (but not 110.)
(?:           # Start of a (repeating) group that matches...
 (?!          #   (if we're not at the start of either...
  \b11\.      #    the number 11.
 |            #    or  
  \bpH\b      #    the string pH
 )            #   )
 .            # any character (including newlines, therefore the DOTALL option).
)*            # Repeat as necessary.
\bpH\b        # Match the string pH
\s*           # Match optional whitespace
(             # Match and capture in group 1:
 \d+          # At least one digit
 (?:[.,]\d+)? # optionally followed by a decimal part
)             # End of capturing group 
(?=           # Assert that the following can be matched afterwards:
 .*           # any number of characters
 \b11\.       # followed by 11.
)             # End of lookahead assertion.
```

Comment: Sounds like a clean and fast way to proceed, but I raised 2 erros : 1.'module' object has no attribute 'SINGLELINE'
 2.'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
Any clue?

Comment: Oops, should be DOTALL - that should fix it. The second error means there was no match - probably a result of the first error.

Comment: No Singleline either, I can't find Singleline in the python doc, are you sure of the word?

Comment: This seems to be accurate.

Comment: But whenever you have time, I would be delighted on more explanations on how the regex works! trying to figure out on regex101 anyway

Comment: @RaphaelMoraglia: Certainly, thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, assuming you can put whatever you want in the 234 spot. This returns everything after the pH symbol that matches "234".

```
import re

my_str = "10. blablablablabla pH 1234 11. 234"
match_list = re.findall(r'10\..*pH.*(234).*11\.', my_str)

print(match_list)
```

Abstractly this looks for a string matching the following pattern: `start_pattern wildcard pre_pattern wildcard captured_pattern wildcard end_pattern` All the wild cards are `.*` which matches 0 or more occurrences of any character. The captured pattern is between the two braces `(my_pattern)` which in this case is `234`

To illustrate my last point better, here is the above with variables:

```
import re

start_pattern = "10\."
end_pattern = "11\."
pre_pattern = "pH"
wildcard = '.*'
captured_pattern = "234"

my_str = "10. blablablablabla pH 1234 11. 234"

match_list = re.findall(r''
                        + start_pattern
                        + wildcard
                        + pre_pattern
                        + wildcard
                        + '(' + captured_pattern + ')'
                        + wildcard
                        + end_pattern
                        , my_str)

print(match_list)
```

Comment: This doesn't restrict the search to the section between `10.` and `11.`.

Comment: Noted... I just updated an extra bit to the regex to hopefully account for this

Comment: in the 1st example piece, you probably don't want `ph.*(234)`, as it seems like the OP wants the numbers immediately following ph. it might be better to do `ph\s*(234`, as this restricts what falls between ph and the number to just whitespace chars

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly I am assuming that a line starting with `10.` will always end with `11.`. If so we only need to find the `10.` and check what comes after that:

```
10\.\s.+(?<=pH )(\d[.,]?\d)(?=\s)
```

This matches the `10.` then anything up to a digit which is preceded by `"pH "` (using a positive look-behind). It then restricts the capture to 2 digits, optionally split by a period or comma

[see demo here](https://regex101.com/r/qF2dP6/2)

#### UPDATE

Based on the clarifications in the comments, this now has the `11.` end delimiter and captures the required digits after the first "pH" found

```
\b10\.\s.+(?<=pH )(\d[.,]?\d)\s.+?\b11\.
```

[updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/qF2dP6/3)

Comment: No, it's not about lines, since we can have many lines between "10." and "11.", document starts with "1." until "16.", so I need both borders